# Twig loop in assoc array

Tags: loops, for-loop, twig

i have array like

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => tratata
        [1] => blabla
    )
    [data_key] => Array (
        [0] => the first key
        [1] =>  the second one
    )
)
```

And i tried to display it this way:

```
{% for key, value in L10_DATA %}
    <tr>
        <th>
            {{ value.data_key }}
        </th>
        <td>
            {{ value.data }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesnt work :c Can you help me, please?

I need to get that king of table, where the first column is `data_key` and the second one - `data`:[image]

Comment: `data_key` and `data` are both arrays. You will need to loop those as well  in order to print the dara

Comment: @DarkBee you mean add `{% for k_key, k_value in value.data_key %}` inside first loop? it also doesnt work

Comment: See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/b0ci05)

Comment: @DarkBee wow :3 thanks, Bee

Comment: @DarkBee buut... it's not actually working. how can i divide `data_key` and `data`? in your example it's displaying in one row

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @DarkBee edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your data is divided into 2 (sub)arrays, you will need to use the index of the first array, to access the data of the second

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th><th>Data</th>
    </tr>
    {% for index, key in L10_DATA.data_key %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td><td>{{ L10_DATA.data[index] }}</td>
    <tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/b0ci05/2)

Comment: WOW. thaks. its exually what i need